# Klipfolio not pulling all items from an app

Tags: api, datasource, podio, klipfolio

I am trying to setup Klipfolio as a KPI dashboard for our work tracked in Podio.

I set up a Klipfolio Data Source for each Podio App we have.

It all seemed to be working until I went to verify the lead source numbers I was seeing in a Klip with numbers in Podio and there was a big discrepancy.

When I examined the Data Source in Klipfolio, I noticed it only had 1000 records, where podio shows 2523 records in the correlating app.

I can't find anything in the Podio API docs that discusses an item limit.

Any ideas on how to configure the Data Source to pull in all items within an app?

Here is the configuration of the Data Source where we know it isn't pulling in all items from Podio:
[Seller Lead Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPYMP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Podio has a 1000 record limit per API call which is why you don't see all 2523 records. You can see this in the parameters section of the Podio API docs for Get Items: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-items-27803

If you want to pull all lead records you'll need to paginate. Klipfolio has an excellent tutorial that walks through pagination with Podio here: https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210312977-Klipfolio-Datasource-Pagination-with-Podio-